# How can I fill out web page timesheets using selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, browser-automation

I have to fill out my timesheet data every friday in timesheets.

I've heard that selenium can be used to automate such manual tasks.

I don't have a programming background - how would I use selenium to do this?
Do I download an editor or something?

Comment: Can you add more detail to what you want. What you have tried. Just putting a one liner question is of no use.

Comment: Is this for QA or simple automation? For quick automation, you will have faster results using tools with a recorder like iMacros or Kantu Automation.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has the tag WebDriver but in this case I would consider the Selenium IDE

Download and install the Firefox Selenium IDE plug-in - [Selenium IDE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/)

Start using it and learn how to use its functions to:

- Visit a page
- Click on elements
- Enter data in input fields
- Select dropdown options
- Submit forms

A final note - I love browser automation but I wouldn't use it for time sheet filling.
Too likely to have a unnoticed error IMHO.  I'm sure it would start at 8 hours every day, never changes but at some point you or others would hit a snag, incorrect or invalid data and when it comes to timesheet entry that can make a real mess and get you into trouble.  Your explanation that you were using automation to fill it out would just make the situation worse.

Comment: +1. For the final note: For a toy project, play with something simple, where consequences if you do it wrong are minimal to none.